# How to switch activity in android without .class

Tags: android

In android i have total 3 files 1 activity_main.xml
2 nd MainActivity.java and now 3 file is activity2.xml i want to switch from activity_main.xml to activity2.xml(No java source, Only XML file of activity2.xml)

Comment: Each XML layout file should have a corresponding .java file which contains a class which extends Activity. By trying to avoid doing this, you are avoiding a principal design pattern of Android development.

Comment: If you want to change layout for single `Activity` you can  change it with `setContentView(R.layout.activity2)`, but I recommend you to use `Fragment` for that.

Comment: Thank you all  i found my solution in Dumbo Answer